# Canon MF4770n driver installation for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I installed the driver and it seems to be installed fine, since it gets rendered, but it never gets to the printer. It will not even print a test page so far.

I would be happy to even use a generic printer driver as I do NOT need any fancy function(s), I just want to be able to print and scan.

The printer is new and was previously used with no problems with Windows.

Thank you, Alan

Comment: This worked for me http://askubuntu.com/a/226333/46496

Answer (score 2):

I recently installed this driver on Ubuntu 15.10 64bit.

First download the driver from Canon's website. The URL has changed from previous answers.

https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/black-and-white-laser/mf4770n

The Canon website may autodetect your browser as generic Linux instead of 32bit or 64bit. If this is the case, select the correct one to see the specific driver to download. Extract this file (.tar.gz) through the file browser or terminal. Next, enter the directory and install the driver (your driver version may be newer).

```
cd ~/Downloads/Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V310_us_EN/
sudo sh install.sh
```

After this is complete, you can go into your **System Settings -> Printers** and add it as a network printer. For me, the driver was autodetected and I only needed to name the printer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply install the official driver from Canon, and add printer using `system-config-printer` or `cups web interface (http://localhost:631)`
http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/printers_multifunction/black_white_laser_multifunction/imageclass_mf4770n#DriversAndSoftware

Answer (score -1):

Almost all the all-in one Printers dont need additional drivers for act in Ubuntu.

Install all printer drivers and scanner drivers and use the printer with the application `system-config-printer-gnome` and scanner with the application `simple scan`:

Printer packages

```
sudo apt-get install cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-filters cups-ppdc cups-server-common debconf ghostscript libavahi-client3 libavahi-common3 libc-bin libc6 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libgcc1 libstdc++6 libusb-1.0-0 lsb-base poppler-utils procps system-config-printer-gnome
```

Scanner Packages

```
sudo apt-get install sane xsane xsane-common sane-utils libsane libsane-common libsane-dbg libsane-dev libsane-extras libsane-extras-common libsane-extras-dbg libsane-extras-dev simple-scan
```